# Authentication strategy 'jwt' is not registered

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, feathersjs, google-appengine-node

#### Steps to reproduce

I deployed my featherjs sample project that required authentication to Google Appengine and I get the following error message:

```
{
    "name": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Authentication strategy 'jwt' is not registered.",
    "code": 400,
    "className": "bad-request",
    "errors": {}
}
```

My app engine logs show the following:

> error: BadRequest: Authentication strategy 'jwt' is not registered.
>   at new BadRequest (/srv/node_modules/@feathersjs/errors/lib/index.js:86:17)
>   at Object. (/srv/node_modules/@feathersjs/authentication/lib/hooks/authenticate.js:41:29)
>   at promise.then.hookObject (/srv/node_modules/@feathersjs/commons/lib/hooks.js:167:73)
>   at < anonymous >

Is there anyway to force register JWT? This works fine in my featherjs dev environment so there isn't anything wrong with the setup for a normal environment just wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to get it running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/feathersjs/authentication-local/issues/4#issuecomment-269802828) seemed to solve my issue

```
app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(app.get('auth').strategies)
      ],
      remove: authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
    }
});
```